# How to share the same mongoose default connection throughout multiple files mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't find a solution as to how I can share a mongoose connection accross multiple files , here is an example

**User.js**

```
 var mongoose = require("../DataAccess/DbConnection");
 var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true,maxlength: 40,unique:true},
 });

var User = mongoose.model('User', tutorSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**DbConnection.js**

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'test')
{
    if(!mongoose.connection)
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
}
else
{
    if(!mongoose.connection)
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nottest');
}
module.exports = mongoose
```

But it doesn't work any way , I saved a User in the test database 
Now in my User Test I am trying to remove a User

**UserTest.js**

```
   process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
   var mongoose=require("../DataAccess/DbConnection");
   var User =new require('../../models/User');
   User.remove({}, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Successfully cleared");
        }
        else {

            console.log("error clearing tutor during test");
        }
```

But it doesn't work , I can't remove any object from the collection , even the find function is not also working. The thing that works is that if I explicitly declare these two lines in each of the files ,

```
if(!mongoose.connection)
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Comment: I'm learning this stuff too.  Have you tried `var db_connection = mongoose.connection;` and sent that out as the export item?  How do you know that DBConnection.js implements before the other two files need to use the connection?  Is this an async issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the following solution

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

if (mongoose.connection.readyState == 0) {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

}
module.exports = mongoose;
```